# Ios Sourcemaps not applied - Sentry

Tags: ios, source-maps, sentry, react-native-sentry

Cannot get React Native IOS Source maps to apply.
The distribution and release match.
If RN is in debug mode then everything matches appropriately.

> sentry-cli releases files “n.sdsadas.dasdsadas@2.0.0+2.0.0.14”
> upload-sourcemaps < path > --dist 2.0.0.14
>
> sentry-cli upload-dysym < path >
>
> sentry-cli upload-dif --include-sources < path >

The source maps ~/main.jsbundle and ~/main.jsbundle.map have uploaded and are dist tagged appropriately.

Two dsyms upload, one with the sources (sourcebundle) tag, and the other with the debug and symtab (macho debug companion)

Something to do with rewrite frames integration? Any ideas?

Thanks

[image: sourcemaps]

[image: dsyms]

[image: error]

[image: error device]

Comment: Did you find the answer? ;()